Adding adsense manually to wordpress
I have a free wordpress website and I need to add adsense to it. All of the instructions I can find online refer to a different version of wordpress that I don't have access to. I should be able to add it manually to the header.php code but I can't work out where to access it. Can anyone help?

It sounds like you're using wordpress.com, which won't let you edit the templates. You can find out more about the difference between wordpress.com and wordpress.org here.

The internet is full of instructions on how to add adsense to wordpress.com sites. So is this no longer possible?

The internet is full of instructions on how to add adsense to sites running WordPress, but they mean the WordPress software downloaded from wordpress.org and installed on a generic hosting account. No matter how I massage my search terms I can't find any that are specific to wordpress.com.
